What determines $libdir in PostgreSQL?
Looking at the PostgreSQL/15/data directory on a Windows machine, I found the postgresql.conf file.
In the file, it has #dynamic_library_path = '$libdir'
What determines what $libdir is set to and how can I change it?

I think $libdir can be set when compiling Postgres. If you want to set a custom $libdir placeholder value, you could rebuild Postgres with the configure script, passing in --libdir=DIR. I'm not sure if/how it can be modified safely in the post-install phase.

Notes on setting $libdir here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/install-procedure.html
